# Building a DbCommand to compare two columns on Variants

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, createcommand

I am trying to compare two fields located on Variants in Commerce. One is the price field and then I also have an original price field which is a custom field. I want to compare and get all variants where the price is less than the original price.

```
$query = craft()->db->createCommand()
            ->from('commerce_variants')
            ->where("price < field_originalPrice")
            ->queryAll();

return $query;
```

This is what I have so far but could be way off on this since that custom field is actually on the `content` table.

Any help would be awesome! Thanks!

Comment: You want _all_ of the variants that currently have a price less than their corresponding "field_originalPrice" value?  Or just a particular one?

Comment: I'd like to get all the variants and then can group them by their associated product after the fact. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Completely untested, but this should return all variants whose `price` column's value is less than your custom field's `originalPrice` value.

```
$results = craft()->db->createCommand()
    ->select('v.*')
    ->from('commerce_variants v')
    ->join('content c', 'v.id = c.elementId')
    ->where('v.price < c.field_originalPrice")
    ->queryAll();
```

Comment: Awesome thank you Brad, will give this a shot!